# Rails: ActiveAdmin + Devise

Tags: devise, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Good afternoon. I'm a beginner in Rails and I'm starting this project in college and I need some help. I have users that don't need sign up. I will create all the users. Then, I decided to use the gem ActiveAdmin, and I can add the users through the graphic interface. I thought it would be easy but, after finish the installation, I tried to add some user and I've got a surprise:
  I have all those fields created by devise to edit.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAK1h.png

I wanna know if there is a way that I can edit only the fields created by me, and those other fields automatically fill, like if I'm creating a new user with devise.

P.S: I wanna just lines to follow, not the entire resolution. I'm really lost rs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set which inputs you want to appear in your form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

The rest of the inputs will be filled by Devise.

Docs for ActiveAdmin form: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md